# soracom-sdk-rubyのregister_subscriberが実行できない

Tags: ruby, soracom

Amazonで購入したsoracomのSIMをAPIで登録しようとたのですが上手く行きません。
soracom-sdk-rubyのregister_subscriberを実行するとArgumentErrorが発生します。

```
#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)>
```

次の様なクラスを作成し、register_simでSDKのregister_subscriberメソッドをコールしてテストしました。

```
class SimDevice
  def client
    @soracom ||= Soracom::Client.new(
      auth_key_id: SORACOM_AUTH_KEY_ID,
      auth_key: SORACOM_AUTH_KEY_SECRET
    )
  end

  def register_sim
    imsi = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    registration_secret = 'XXXXX'  # PASSCODE ??
    client.register_subscriber(imsi, registration_secret)  # Error
  end
end
```

質問が２点あります。
１．APIドキュメントに書いてあるregistrationSecretは、SIMカードに記載されているPASSCODEで良いか？

２．もし１が合っている場合、register_subscriberメソッドをどの様に利用すればよいか？

ご存知の方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

（参考）
・soracom-sdk-ruby
https://github.com/soracom/soracom-sdk-ruby

・APIドキュメント
https://dev.soracom.io/jp/docs/api/

Answer (score 1):

1. はその通りです。2. について回答します。

キーワード引数を使ってメソッドが定義されていますので、メソッドの呼び出しの際に、変数名を以下のように明示する必要があります。

```rb
client.register_subscriber(imsi: imsi, registration_secret: registration_secret)
```

https://github.com/soracom/soracom-sdk-ruby/blob/master/lib/soracom/client.rb#L81

ご参考までに、提示されたサンプルコードを単独で動作するように少しだけ手を加えてみました。

```rb
require 'soracom'
class SimDevice
  def client
    @soracom ||= Soracom::Client.new(
      auth_key_id: SORACOM_AUTH_KEY_ID,
      auth_key: SORACOM_AUTH_KEY_SECRET
    )
  end

  def register_sim
    imsi = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    registration_secret = 'XXXXX'
    client.register_subscriber(imsi: imsi, registration_secret: registration_secret)or
  end
end

p SimDevice.new().register_sim # => {"code"=>"SEM0001", "message"=>"No such resource found"}
```

正しいIMSIとパスコードを与えれば動作すると思われます。

Comment: 上記コードで動作することを確認いたしました。ありがとうございます。